# How to trim several textfield in swift at once?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have several textfield in a page. Currently i'm trimming every textfield one by one like code below.

```
public struct CustomerAddressDetail: Encodable {
 public var fullname: String?
 public var identifierNumber: String?
}

var customerInfoDetail = CustomerInfoDetail()

customerInfoDetail.fullname = itemsInput[0][0].value?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) ?? ""
customerInfoDetail.identifierNumber = itemsInput[0][1].value?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) ?? ""
```

I try to trim multiple value at once. Because it looks like a bad way to trim it one by one

Is it really like that ? Or is there any better way to trim multiple item ?

Comment: You may iterate  over your itemsInput array in a loop to shorten the code and trimm the elements

Comment: i've thought about that. It's true about shorten the code. But, is it a good way ? Because, it seems like work 2 times for the same or similar things  @popeinvestor

Comment: Where the data came from? You may restrict the input to avoid trimming

Comment: You still have to trim each value so I am not sure what kind of solution you are expecting with this question. You could trim in the `willSet` for each property or you could trim the value when adding it to `itemsInput` etc etc, which one is "best" depends on the use case and/or is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: Off topic but why use both optional properties _and_ nil coalescing?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Okay, it means whatever way. I still needs to do it  for each value 

 about optional properties, Just in case the API return something null. Is it bad?

Comment: I never said it was bad but if you always supply a default value then you don't need to user optional properties and most of the time this simplifies things further on when you are accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks bad to you because you have duplicate code. A nicer way to it is using iteration or map like this:

```
let stringlist: [String] = ["a ", "b ", "c "]
let trimmedlist = stringlist.map { s in
    return s.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
}
```